# how to place the images exactly in menu position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi in the below code i want to display navigationMenu and slider in a same line.But my problem is both are displaying in same line but images got giving left side some space.

How to move the images to left with the width and height.

**html**

```
<div id="main">

<ul id="navigationMenu">
   <li>
        <a class="home" href="index.html">
            <span>Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="about" href="About.html">
            <span>About Us</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
         <a class="services" href="Specialties.html">
            <span>Specialties</span>
         </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="portfolio" href="facilities.html">
            <span>Facilities</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="contact" href="Contact.html">
            <span>Contact us</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

</div> 
<div id="sliders1">
      <div id="slider">
      <div class="gallery">
        <ul class="images">
          <li class="show"><img style="padding-right:40px" width:950;height:300px" src="img/1.jpg" alt="photo_one" /></li>
          <li><img width="950" height="300" src="img/2.jpg" alt="seascape" /></li>
          <li><img width="950" height="300" src="img/3.jpg" alt="seascape" /></li>
          <li><img width="950" height="300" src="img/4.jpg" alt="seascape" /></li>
          <li><img width="950" height="300" src="img/5.jpg" alt="seascape" /></li>
          <li><img width="950" height="300" src="img/6.jpg" alt="seascape" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

**css**

```
#sliders1 {   
  width: 1050px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0px auto 0px 120px;
  height:300px;
} 
.gallery{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

ul.images {
  width:1050px;
  height:100%;

  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  margin:0px auto;
  padding:0;

} 

ul.images li {
  position:absolute;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  list-style:none;
}

ul.images li.show {
  z-index:500; 
  width:1050px;
  height:300px;
 overflow:hidden;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}

ul.images  li img {
  border-style: none;
   width:1050px;
  height:100%; 
   outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `position` attribute of `main` **ID** div to `absolute`. Use this:

```
position:absolute;
```

> Note: You are facing problem because of right side section `main`
>   **ID** consuming space.

Full css:

```
#main {
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: absolute;/*changed*/
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrap {

    position: relative;

}
nav {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```